# How to remove a table within a table with google appScript

Tags: google-apps-script

So these are the methods within my code that I am pulling parts of the template.  I am able to remove specific tables from the template with removeFromParent();

My problem now is I have one table that has 2 tables imbedded in a cell.  How can I delete one of these two imbedded tables?

(FYI the table is used for formatting and alignment only so it is a single cell table with two other tables imbedded into it)

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copiedTemplateId);
var body = doc.getBody();
var header = doc.getHeader();
var table = body.getTables();
```

...
table[6].removeFromParent();

Still haven't found a command that would perform this function.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation of `How can I delete one of these two imbedded tables?`. About `FYI the table is used for formatting and alignment only so it is a single cell table with two other tables imbedded into it`, which table do you want to delete?

Comment: Imagine a one cell table (just used as framing of content) and within that one cell I have 2 different tables.  I want to delete one of the inside tables.

Answer (score 0):

From your following reply,

> Imagine a one cell table (just used as framing of content) and within that one cell I have 2 different tables. I want to delete one of the inside tables.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set `deleteTable` and `const table = tables[6]`. `const table = tables[6]` is from your showing script `table[6].removeFromParent()`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const deleteTable = 1; // The 1st table and 2nd table are 1 and 2, respectively.
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const tables = doc.getBody().getTables();
  const table = tables[6]; // Please set your table.
  const cell = table.getCell(0, 0);
  const tablesInCell = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cell.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    const c = cell.getChild(i);
    if (c.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
      tablesInCell.push(c);
    }
  }
  if (tablesInCell.length == 0) return;
  tablesInCell[deleteTable - 1].removeFromParent();
}
```

- When this script is run, the 1st cell of the table is retrieved. And, one of the tables in a cell is removed.

#### Reference:

- [removeFromParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#removeFromParent())